# how to add an element to devise session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am working with rails and devise for authentication, I want to add an element to the session hash, if I was using the native authentication session i would do session[:cart_id], but with devise I dont know if that would work or how to do it the devise way, for now I made a relationship between the customer model and the cart model: a customer has one cart, that way I can access the cart using customer.cart but I saw that many people dont relate the cart to the customer that way, they just create the cart and keep the id in the session hash. *so my questions are:*

**1- How to add an element to the session with devise?**

**2- Relating the Cart model with the Customer model (a customer has one cart) is a correct approach or should I try to go with the cart_id in the session hash?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise don't change anything to the session, it may use keys like :user_return_to (given your devise session is "user") but mostly you are free to use the session as you wish.

Session[:cart_id] is fine, do not store anything like a model in session, store its id instead, and fetch the corresponding record from the database from the database when access is needed.

See also this chapter about session storage: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage